# How to load the tags Data of MovieLens to Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to load the [Tags Data](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-10m-README.html) of MovieLens to matlab. I used importdata function but this function only imports first row.
`importdata('E:\m1-10M100K\tags.dat',':');`

Tags Data File Structure:
Each line of this file represents one tag applied to one movie by one user, and has the the following format:

UserID::MovieID::Tag::Timestamp

this is first line of the file:
15::4973::excellent!::1215184630

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you expecting that the users study the documentation you linked? Give significant examples please. There also a lot of alternatives to `importdata` what have you tried? What about the importdata-tool of matlab? It can generate code, try that out.

Comment: I added file format, the importdata function imports data in incorrect format. I want to import data in matrix.

Comment: @thewaywewalk, i used importdata-tool but result didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, this code  loads the Tags Data of MovieLens to Matlab.

```
fid = fopen('E:\ml-10M100K\tags.dat','r');
InputText=textscan(fid,'%d%s%d%s%s%s%d',4,'delimiter','::','endofline','\n');
```